# What is the rationale behind variable assignment without space in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write an automate process for AWS that requires some JSON processing and other things in bash script. I am following a few blogs for bash script and I found this:

```
a=b
```

with the following note:

> There is no space on either side of the equals ( = ) sign. We
>   also leave off the $ sign from the beginning of the variable name when
>   setting it

This is ugly and very difficult to read and comparing to other scripting languages, it is easy for user to make a mistake when writing a bash script by leaving space in between. I think everyone like to write clean and readable code, this restriction for sure is bad for code readability.

Can you explain why? explanation with examples are highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that this is broader than just Bash. I think any shell based on the Bourne shell has the same rule, so e.g. Zsh, Ksh, Ash.

Comment: I always thought it was just defined as such. `word` - A sequence of characters considered as a single unit by the shell. Also known as a token. `name` - A `word` consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore. Also referred to as an identifier. `PARAMETERS` A `parameter` is an entity that stores values. ... A `variable` is a parameter denoted by a `name`. ... A `variable` may be assigned to by a statement of the form `name=[value]`. (See, e.g. *man bash*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because otherwise the syntax would be ambiguous. Consider this command line:

```
cat = foo
```

Is that an assignment to the variable `cat`, or running the command `cat` with the arguments "=" and "foo"? Note that "=" and "foo" are both perfectly legal filenames, and therefore reasonable things to run `cat` on. Shell syntax settles this in favor of the command interpretation, so to avoid this interpretation you need to leave out the spaces. `cat =foo` has the same problem.

On the other hand, consider:

```
var= cat
```

Is that the command `cat` run with the variable `var` set to the empty string (i.e. a shorthand for `var='' cat`), or an assignment to the shell variable `var`? Again, the shell syntax favors the command interpretation so you need to avoid the temptation to add spaces.

There are many places in shell syntax where spaces are important delimiters. Another commonly-messed-up place is in tests, where if you leave out *any* of the spaces in:

```
if [ "$foo" = "$bar" ]
```

...it will lead to a different meaning, which might cause an error, or might just silently do the wrong thing.

What I'm getting at is that shell syntax does not allow you to arbitrarily add or remove spaces to improve readability. Don't even try, you'll just break things.

Comment: Re the last paragraph, the difference between 0 and 1 spaces is syntactically important, but between 1 and more is not.

Comment: "...to avoid this interpretation you need to leave out the spaces." The word *need* is incorrect. One could simply quote the equal sign, same as one would quote `cat\=foo` today if an assignment weren't actually desired.

Comment: @JohnKugelman That'd be true if the original shell designers had decided the assignment interpretation took precedence, but they decided that spacing should be the deciding factor. There're a lot of parts of shell syntax that come down to "well, this is the choice someone made back in the day, and we've been working around it ever since," and I'd consider this one of them.

Comment: @GordonDavisson so from your explanation a statement in bash script can be interpreted as a command? Or it is interpreted as a command?

Comment: @channaly With spaces, it *will* be interpreted as a command rather than an assignment.

Answer (score 7):

What you need to understand is that the shell language and syntax is old.  Really old.  The first version of the  UNIX shell with variables was the Bourne shell which was designed and implemented in 1977.  Back then, there were few precedents.  (AFAIK, just the [Thompson shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_shell), which didn't support variables according to the manual entry.)

The rationale for the design decisions in the 1970's are ... lost in the mists of time.  The design decisions were made by Steve Bourne and colleagues working at Bell Labs on v6 UNIX.  They probably had no idea that their decisions would still be relevant 40+ years later.

The Bourne shell was designed to be general purpose and simple to use ... compared with the alternative of writing programs in C.  And small.  It was an outstanding success in those terms.

However, any language that is successful has the "problem" that it gets widely adopted.  And that makes it more difficult to fix any issues (real or perceived) that may arise.  Any proposal to change a language needs to be balanced against the impact of that change on existing users / uses of the language.  You *don't want to* break existing programs or scripts.

Irrespective of arguments about whether spaces around `=` should be allowed in a shell variable assignment, changing this would *break* millions of shell scripts.  It is just not going to happen.

Of course, Linux (and UNIX before it) allow you to design and implement your own shell.  You could (in theory) replace the default shell.  It is just a lot of work.

And there is nothing stopping you from writing your scripts in another scripting language (e.g. Python, Ruby, Perl, etc) or designing and implementing your own scripting language.

---

In summary:

We cannot know *for sure* why they designed the shell with this syntax for variable assignment, but it is moot anyway.

---

Reference:

- [Evolution of shells in Linux: a history of shells](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-linux-shells/#a-history-of-shells).

Answer (score 3):

It prevents ambiguity in a lot of cases. Otherwise, if you have a statement `foo = bar`, it could then either mean run the `foo` program with `=` and `bar` as arguments, or set the `foo` variable to `bar`. When you require that there are no spaces, now you've limited ambiguity to the case where a program name contains an equals sign, which is basically unheard of.

Comment: I don't see how it prevents ambiguity. If spaces were allowed then `foo = bar` would simply be defined as a legal assignment, just as `foo=bar` defined as an assignment and not a command name today. Quoting (`foo \= bar` or `foo '=' bar`) would disable the behavior, same as today (`foo\=bar` or `foo'='bar`).

Comment: @JohnKugelman You described a way the ambiguity could be resolved, but that doesn't mean that it never existed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @StephenC, and here's some more context with sources:

Unix v6 from 1975 did not have an environment, there was just a [`exec` syscall](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/2/exec) that took a program and a string array of  arguments. The system `sh`, written by Thompson, did not support variables, [only single digit numbered arguments](https://github.com/lewischeng-ms/v6/blob/7c453cde48c60c1c57cf69be3ee88ecd12aabcb0/src/s2/sh.c#L281) like `$1` (probably why `$12` to this day is interpreted as `${1}2`)

Unix v7 from 1979, emboldened by advances in hardware, added a ton of features including [a second string array](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/2/exec) to the `exec` call. The [`man` page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/5/environ/) described it like this, which is still how it works to this day:

> An array of strings called the `environment` is made available by exec(2) when a process begins.  By convention these strings have the form `name=value`

The system `sh`, now written by Bourne, worked much like v6 shell, but now allowed you to specify these environment strings in the same format in front of commands (because which other format would you use?). The simplistic parser essentially split words by spaces, and [flagged a word as destined for a variable](https://github.com/v7unix/v7unix/blob/ed636a47207476db76d53b7869447889dee3bbad/v7/usr/src/cmd/sh/word.c#L33) if it contained a `=` and all preceding characters had been alphanumeric.

Thanks to Unix v7's incredible popularity, forks and clones copied a lot of things including this behavior, and that's what we're still seeing today.